# Sufficient conditions for positive semidefiniteness of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nonnegative-matrices, block-matrices

$\newcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}$I m looking for sufficient conditions that *may* guarantee **positive semidefiniteness** (PSD) of a *block matrix*
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} A_{1,1} & \cdots & A_{1,n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A_{n,1} & \cdots & A_{n,n}\end{bmatrix}$$
with consistent block dimensions, $A_{i,j} \in \Re^{d_i \times d_j}$.
I'm aware of the sufficient condition that if $A$ is *block diagonally dominant* (BDD) this implies PSD [1], but the BDD condition turns to be too restrictive for my case of interest (my block matrices are not BDD, yet they are PSD).
I looked for some alternative but couldn't find anything in the literature. Also I'm not interested in Schur-based exact conditions, but simpler conditions that work well often (but not necessarily always).

In looking at the *block diagonally dominant* (BDD) condition [1] I came up with a proposal which I briefly describe here.
First, consider the traditional BDD condition [1] from the following perspective:

- Build the $n\times n$ matrix $M \in \Re_+^{n\times n}$ given as
  $$M=[m_{ij}]_{i,j=1}^n, \quad m_{ij} = \begin{cases} \inf_{x} \frac{||A_{ij}x||_2}{||x||_2} \text{ if } i=j\\ \sup_{x} \frac{||A_{ij}x||_2}{||x||_2} \text{ if } i\neq j \end{cases}$$
- Considering this *condensed* matrix $M$, the traditional BDD condition [1] on $A$ is equivalent to the condition that $M$ is *Diagonally Dominant* (DD). Thus, we can state **$M$ is DD $\implies$ $A$ is PSD**.

### Conjecture

Now, my first hunch was that maybe the relationship **$M$ is PSD $\implies$ $A$ is PSD** would stand.
However, after some extensive numerical testing, I've found cases where my conjecture is contradicted. That is, **$M$ is PSD $\nRightarrow$ $A$ is PSD**.

#### A contradiction example

For completeness, I'm including here a simple numerical example where the conjecture fails.
Consider the 3x3 block-matrix with block-dimension 2x2 (also available for download [here](http://mapir.isa.uma.es/jbriales/temp/contradiction.csv)):
$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
1.0  &  0.6  & -0.3  &  0.4  &  0.2  & -0.2\\
0.6  &  1.6  &  0.5  & -0.6  & -0.4  &  0.4\\
\hline
-0.3 &  0.5  & 78.6  & 79.8  &  0.1  & -0.1\\
0.4  & -0.6  & 79.8  & 84.2  & -0.3  &  0.2\\
\hline
0.2  & -0.4  &  0.1  & -0.3  &  3.5  &  0.5\\
-0.2 &  0.4  & -0.1  &  0.2  &  0.5  &  3.3
\end{array}\right]$$
This has the following eigenvalues $eig(A)=\{-0.0372 ,   1.6458 ,   2.3249    ,3.1036   , 3.9136 , 161.2494\}$, so it's indefinite.
The condensed matrix M as defined above is
$$ M = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0.6292  &  0.9271  &  0.6325\\
    0.9271  &  1.5509  &  0.3864\\
    0.6325  &  0.3864  &  2.8901
\end{array}\right]$$
with eigenvalues $eig(M)=\{0.0129, 1.7594,    3.2978\}$, so it's positive definite, contradicting the conjecture above.

It's obvious that the simple proposed relation does not fulfill the PSD test I was looking for. Still, for this and other cases I found so far, even though $A$ was *not* PSD, it wasn't too far (the negative eigenvalue was small).
So I still wonder if the proposed relationship **$M$ is PSD $\implies$ $A$ is PSD** might stand under additional constraints.

I would appreciate if anyone has anything to contribute on this.
I am assuming some properties on $A$ to simplify the problem, so $A$ can be considered symmetric, and the blocks all square with $d_i=d_j=d$.

### Analysis using block Cholesky decomposition

So far, I tried to look at this using [the block variant of Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Block_variant) as a PSD test, so that if each diagonal sub-block in the block Cholesky decomposition is PSD, then the block matrix is PSD.

#### Special case: 2x2 block-matrix

Using the sufficient conditions from Cholesky decomposition, the 2x2 block case fulfills the proposed relationship.
Consider the 2x2 block Cholesky decomposition

$$A = LDL^\top = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ L_{21} & I \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} D_1 & 0 \\ 0 & D_2 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & L_{21}^\top \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}$$

By the properties of the Cholesky decomposition, **{$D_1$ is PSD, $D_2$ is PSD} $\implies$ $A$ is PSD**.
Since $D_1 = A_{11}$ and $D_2 = A_{22} - A_{21} A_{11}^\top A_{12}$,
it follows that:
$$ m_{11} \geq 0 \implies D_1 \text{ is PSD} $$
$$ m_{11} - m_{21} m_{22}^{-1} m_{12} \geq 0 \implies D_2 \text{ is PSD} $$
The left hand inequality in the second expression can be written as $m_{11}m_{22} \geq m_{12} m_{21} = det(M) \geq 0$.

The sufficient conditions above for **$A$ is PSD** are clearly fulfilled if **$M$ is PSD** (just consider Sylvester criterion).

### #

#### General case: nxn block matrix

As soon as we go further than 2x2, the expressions from Cholesky decomposition become more complex, and just forcing **$M$ is PSD** does not seem enough to provide sufficient conditions for PSD of $A$.

PD: I posted this same question some time ago in math.stackexchange, but didn't get any answer so far. So I was wondering if this might be a more appropriate forum to pose the question.

[1] Feingold, D. G., & Varga, R. S. (1962). Block diagonally dominant matrices and generalizations of the Gerschgorin circle theorem. Pacific J. Math, 12(4), 1241-1250.

Comment: What is your case of interest? Could you post an example where $M$ is PSD but $A$ is not?

Comment: I just added a numerical example. About my case of interest, I'm working on some problems such as Rotation Synchronization where a fundamental step involving testing global optimality involves checking the Positive Semidefiniteness of a given block-matrix (nxn (dxd)-blocks, with n large and d small).
I was looking for a sufficient test for checking the PSD, exploiting somehow the block-structure to make the process faster (e.g. computing eigenvalues in a condensed matrix M would be way faster than on A).

Let me know if you want further details on this!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the field, so any extra insight on the nature of the block structure would be helpful. How is $A$ built in practice?